# Samsung Galaxy S3 Latest Firmware Contacts App Lag Issue

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have upgraded my phone to the latest firmware which is MainBand : I9300XXLFB.

Before that release no problem was recognized with the contacts app. But now; I am facing with an issue that; it takes 3 to 5 secs to load the contacs list.

Is this a specific one for me or a global issue ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue right after the update. My situation was far worse. If I were to receive a call from 'specific' contacts, the phone would crash (com.android.phone module) and I wouldn't be able to answer it, let alone identify who was calling.

The simple solution for this problem is to Export all your contacts onto your internal SD card. Transfer them over to your computer and Import them by Kies. (This method solved my issue. Maybe it will help you too.

Regards,
Sterex

Comment: well since I have problems with kies as well. That my phone is unable be found on Kies. I think I got real problems with this g s3

Comment: Ok. Kies via data cable also does not work? :(

Comment: Correct. Kies via cable not working. I think the old caches I moved from my old android device corrupts it. I need to go to factory settings. But it needs some times for that operation.

Comment: I am not sure if this problem still exists but I've experienced that some contact apps may cause android to crash. My phone was crashing in the contacts edit menu ( indeed, unable to go to the edit screen ) But I see that the problem was with an app that tries to handle some events.